# Десериализация. При выводе информации из файла выводится только первая запись

Tags: c#

Цель: ввести информацию о студентах => записать в файл => вывести из файла(в консоль).

Никаких ошибок не происходит, но работает не совсем так как мне надо. Когда запускается функция вывода записей, в консоль выводится только первая добавленная в файл запись.

*Подскажите, что я делаю не так...*

**Добавление записи в файл:**

```
        public static void AddString()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string path = "info.dat";
            bool exit = true;
            while (exit)
            {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tВведите данные студента:");

                    Console.WriteLine("\nФ.И.О: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nКурс: ");
                    int course = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("\nГруппа: ");
                    string group = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nНомер зачётки: ");
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("\nСредний балл: ");
                    float avg = (float)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Clear();
                    Student student = new Student(name, course, group, id, avg);
                    Student[] students = new Student[] { student };
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        formatter.Serialize(stream, students);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nУспешно добавлен.");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nХотите добавить ещё одного студента?\n\n1)Да\n2)Нет\n");
                    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("OK.");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            exit = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tОшибка ввода!");
                            Console.WriteLine("\tПопробуйте снова.\n\tНажмите 'Ввод' для продолжения...\n\t");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

**Вывод всех записей из файла:**

```
public static void StudentList()
        {
            string path = "info.dat";
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Student[] students = (Student[])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                Console.WriteLine("Список студентов:");
                foreach (Student student in students)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nИмя: {student.Name} \nКурс: {student.Course} \nГруппа: {student.Group} \nНомер зачётки: {student.Id} \nСредний балл: {student.AvgMark}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Ну так вы туда и записываете постоянно одну запись, ибо постоянно делаете `Student[] students = new Student[] { student };`.

Comment: Представьте, что у вас есть кошелек, в нем предположим 10 рублей, вы хотите положить туда еще допустим 100 рублей, ваши действия? Наверно вы достанете кошелек, откроете его, положите туда новую купюру, закроете, ну и уберете обратно, верно? Или вы купите новый кошелек, положите туда эти 100 рублей (сейчас вы делаете это)? Вот также и тут, вы должны сначала прочитать файл (если есть), вытянуть от туда старые данные и уже к этим старым данным добавлять/удалять новое и уже в конце, то, что вы получили, записать обратьно в файл.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , с добавлением записей в файл проблем нет, если открыть его (info.dat) вручную, то я вижу там все записи которые добавил.

Comment: Нет, @EvgeniyZ прав, если Вы сделаете список объектов students и сначала его заполните и только в конце целиком запишите, то все будет норм. Я вас понял, вы надеялись, что FileMode.Append вам поможет, но тут это не работает. Вам принципиально нужно при каждом новом студенте его сразу записывать ? вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525958/append-to-file-using-binaryformatter) то же решают что делать с этим. Самый простой вариант - всегда записывать все сразу, а при редактировании сначала вычитать данные из файла в коллекцию, изменить ее и снова записать целиком

Comment: @PavelPopov, теперь понял, попробую сделать так как Вы предложили. Только у меня возникает вопрос, теперь чтобы добавить информацию об ещё одном студенте мне нужно будет перезаписать файл целиком?

Comment: Так точно! Если вы начали новый цикл добавления, ты предварительно в коллекцию students вычитываете из файла, работаете именно над коллекцией(добавляете, удаляете, редактируете) и только в конце(можете даже сделать команду отдельную "Сохранить") все это дело серелизуете целиком

Comment: @PavelPopov, принял! Спасибо за потраченное на меня время :)

Comment: Я оформил как ответ, если посчитаете нужным примите его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я был не прав, BinaryFormatter поддерживает дописывание(ответ ниже), НО только по одному объекту, а не массивом объектов. Но более предпочтительна иная стратегия, что бы не обращаться каждый раз к файлу данных:

- вычитываем все данные из файла в коллекцию объектов;
- работаем только над этой коллекцией(добавляете, удаляете, изменяем);
- после окончания редактирования разом все перезаписываем;

Comment: Ничто не мешает с помощью `BinaryFormatter` дописывать данные. Вполне можно в файл дописывать студентов по одному. И потом читать их по одному в цикле. / Но я согласен, что лучше писать и читать сразу коллекцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возможно я ошибаюсь, я искал решение, но ничего не нашел. Например тут написано, что формат такое не позволяет https://stackoverflow.com/a/17526441/8269227  мне интересно было бы узнать, как это реализовать ?

Comment: Написал ответ с примером

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо! да, видимо проблема была в том, что человек пытался данные в массиве дописать, а нужно было по одному объекту. Меня с бил с толку тот ответ, там видимо был иной контекст

Answer (score 1):

Покажу пример, как можно дописывать записи в файл с помощью `BinaryFormatter` и читать их потом в цикле. Отмечу, что прочитать их сразу все как массив будет уже невозможно.

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
var student1 = new Student { Id = 1, Name = "one" };
var student2 = new Student { Id = 2, Name = "two" };

var bf = new BinaryFormatter();

// Пишем в новый файл
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Create))
    bf.Serialize(fileStream, student1);

// Дописываем
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Append))
    bf.Serialize(fileStream, student2);

// Читаем записи по одной в цикле
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("test.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
    {
        var student = (Student)bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
        Console.WriteLine(student.Id + " " + student.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо, приму к сведению, но в данной ситуации мне это решение не подходит, потому что нужно реализовать функцию по выводу всех студентов в виде таблицы.

Comment: @zipqua - подходит, ещё как подходит. Никто и ничто не запрещает вам выводить всех студентов. / Но пока что не мучайтесь, используйте способ из другого ответа.